# LLDB display of NSDate is inconsistent?

Tags: xcode, nsdate, lldb

I am puzzled by the differences underlined in red below:

[image]

How come this very same NSDate object is displayed in BST in the debug pane, but in GMT in the LLDB terminal when asked to '"Print description of "date"' ?

This is with Xcode 4.6.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `NSDate` represents a specific moment in time, without any consideration of what human beings call that moment. If you look at `NSDate`, you'll notice that there aren't even `hour`, `minute`, or `second` properties, let alone a `timeZone` property. The time zone is a feature of the `NSCalendar` used to interpret that `NSDate` for display. (You may be more familiar with `NSDateFormatter`; it internally uses an `NSCalendar` to interpret the date.)

In this case, Xcode happens to configure the calendar for the variables panel a little differently from how LLDB configures the one for the debug console. I'd have to guess that the debug console is calling `-description`, which always uses UTC, while the variables panel is using a date formatter that respects the current time zone. (Your Mac is configured to use BST, right? If not, that's an odd choice...)

Comment: Yes. DST kicks in at the end of March, so 20130402 is right after ... I am just puzzled that Xcode cannot agree on the time zone/calendar to use depending on which pane you look at ...

Comment: The debug console is just blindly calling `-description` because that's what you do when you want to convert an object to a string for printing. The variables panel is smarter: it's looked at the object and determined it's a date, so it wants to display it in the most useful way it can come up with. The two places display arrays and dictionaries even more differently.

Answer (score 3):

Brent's reply is fine - but I wanted to address one detail specifically. lldb has built in type formatters for many common types including `NSDate`.  If you did `p date` in the debugger console, you would get the same output as you see in the Locals window.  When you right-click/control-clicked on the variable and did 'Print description', it is equivalent to writing `po date` in the console -- as Brent says, it calls the `-description` method.

This isn't a console vrs. Locals window difference, or an Xcode vrs. lldb difference.  One access method is using lldb's built in data formatters and one is calling `-description`.

Comment: btw, one really unimportant implementation detail is that lldb actually calls `_NSPrintForDebugger` which takes an object pointer as its argument, for the `po` command.  gdb did the same thing.  There's also a `_CFPrintForDebugger` function.