# How to change NSDate format when printing it in XCode's lldb?

Tags: ios, xcode, nsdate, lldb

For some time now whenever I want to print NSDate with `po` in XCode's debugger instead of a full datetime format like this

```
2012-02-15 18:55:00 +0000
```

I'm getting something like this

```
February 15, 2012
```

which makes it really hard to work with. I can't really remember changing any settings related to date/time format neither in system preferences nor XCode itself, so I'm a bit puzzled.

Looking forward to getting any hint. Thanks.

Comment: see also this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15582142/lldb-display-of-nsdate-is-inconsistent

Comment: This actually refers to a different problem than formatting of NSDate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lldb only calls the debugDescription method

so override debugDescription...

you can do that in a category for debugging

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. Still don't know though why would that change in the first place.